# Postgres cursor calculation in Talend

Tags: postgresql, jvm, cursor, talend

Data was read from postgres table & written to file using Talend. Table size is 1.8GB with 1,050,000 records and has around 125 columns.

1. Assigned JVM as -Xms256M -Xmx1024M. The job failed due to being out of memory. Postgres keeps the result set in physical memory until the query completes. So the entire JVM was occupied and getting an out of memory issue. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.
2. Enabled Cursor option and kept the value as 100,000 and JVM as -Xms256M -Xmx1024M. Job failed with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I don't understand the concept here. Cursor used here denotes the fetch size of rows. In my case, 100,000 was set. So 100,000 will be fetched and stored in physical memory and it will be pushed to file. Then, the occupied memory will be released and the next batch will be fetched. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Considering my case, with 1,050,000 records it occupies 1.8GB. Each record occupies 1.8KB of size. 100,000 * 1.8 = 180,000KB. So entire size is just 175MB. Why is the job not running with a 1GB JVM? Someone please help me with, how does this process work?

3. Some records got dropped after setting the cursor option in talend. Cannot trace the problem in that.

Comment: can you tell what components you are using in your job and what does the job looks like..it is only tpostgresinput-->tfiledelimitedoutput?

Comment: this link has helped me in the past with memory issues.  Take a look and see if it helps you.  http://kindleconsulting.com/component/zoo/item/managing-jvm-heap-size-in-talend-open-studio.html

Comment: @garpitmzn: Yes. Using those two components alone. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a tPostgresInput component. Disabling the Auto Commit setting in the tPostgresConnection component fixed the problem for me!